# Is the Java OS X Application bundle obsolete?

Tags: java, macos

I am interested in creating a desktop application for Mac OS X in Java, and I was going to use the OS X application bundle (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html), but I just realized that it is very old. MDN lists it as obsolete, and its own revision history says it is deprecated. For icing on the cake, the screenshots look like they were taken from snow leopard.

So, my question: is this really obsolete? Do people even use it anymore? And if I shouldn't use it, what should I use?

Thanks!